# leaflet concentric circles (angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

i need to draw to map 5 concentric circles, like a donut, with event handler on "mouseover" each polygon.
i can't do it by circle() method, so i think do it by GeoJSON
how can i do it?
i have this, but this doesn't work
try to learn this method to further implement

```
    let mp = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          [43.30467224121094, 56.696589064251185],
        ],

      ]
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    'radius': 10000,
    'style': {
      color: "black",
      opacity: 1,
      fillColor: "red",
      fillOpacity: 1
    },
  }
};

L.GeoJSON(mp, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return feature.properties.style
  }
}).addTo(this.MAP);
```

Comment: "i can't do it by circle()" > why not?

Comment: because i need to change opacity on mouseover, on each zone between two closest concentric circles, and these zones must filled different colors. so i need to draw donuts, not circles.